# Chimeny scala - validate source

Tags: scala, mapping, mapstruct

i want to use chimney as Scala automapper , and in library like mapstruct  I got unmappedSourcePolicy where is one the field of source were not use , the code will not compile. If there is any way I can achieve this in chimney or any oher scala auto mapper library?

```java
public class Demo {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public class Demo2 {
    private int x;
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

@org.mapstruct.Mapper(
        unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR
)
public interface  Mapper {

   Mapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( Mapper.class );

   public  Demo2 map(Demo demo);
}
```

In this case when i run clean install in mvn i getting next error:

Unmapped source property: "y". Can it be achieve in chimney or any other scala auto mapper?

Comment: *"the code will not compile"* [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and error message would be helpful.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Add some example with mapstruct, but i need this in chimney.

Comment: To map Demo to Demo2 it should be enough to use `demo.transformInto[Demo2]`, what compilation errors did you get?

Comment: This is the idea , its not failing, and i want to fail compilation as soon not all source properties were called for mapping,

Comment: So do you want to require ALL input fields to be used OR require that ALL fields in target have a source field?

Comment: Chimney does not have option to fail compilation of transformer if field in input is unused. Since all fields in target type need to have some source, without any extra configuration this requirement is limiting derivation only to cases when In can be converted to Out and back again - in such case rather than providing config I would require `Transformer.derive[Out, In]` as evidence of reversibility of transformation. If there is some customization (field rename etc) there is no such feature for `Transformer`s. There is such feature for `Patcher`s but they serve different purpose.

Comment: I've added a ticker for this at https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney/issues/248 , depending on whether there will be some interest in this, we might prioritize it when we'll have some resources.